# Como fazer a resposta entrar imediatamente depois da pergunta?

Tags: php, codeigniter, iterator

Tenho um formulário e quero mandar as perguntas e respostas para um banco de dados. Peguei a pergunta em forma de texto e mandei para um campo **input hidden** e quero inserir a  pergunta e a resposta no banco de dados:

```
<label for="pergunta">Como programar em PHP?</label>
<input type="hidden" name="pergunta[]" value="Como programar em PHP?" />
<input type="text" name="resposta[]" value="Estude na documentação do PHP.net" />
```

Tem várias perguntas alimentadas por um foreach. Como iterar as perguntas com as respostas e obter algo do tipo:

> **Como programar em PHP? Estude na documentação do PHP.net**

Eu pensei em algo como:

```
$pergunta = $_POST["pergunta"]; // vai retornar um array
$resposta = $_POST["resposta"]; // vai retornar um array

foreach(){

}
```

Comment: Seriam varias perguntas e respostas ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 2):

O ideal seria você já inserir a pergunta nas respostas, tipo o código da pergunta, no campo por exemplo

```
<input type="text" name="pergunta[idDaPergunta][resposta]" value="" />
```

No controller você irá pegar

```
$this->input->post("pergunta");
```

Já te trás todos os dados da pergunta e resposta (s).

Comment: Interessante isso !!! Vou dar uma olhada.